# radix argument must be between 2 and 36 on moment date

Tags: javascript, datetime, fullcalendar, momentjs

I'm trying to parse a moment date, specifically this: `2018-12-31 00:00:00` into a particular format. The problem is that I got this error:

> toString() radix argument must be between 2 and 36
>       at Number.toString ()

this is my code:

```
function format_date(event, addHours){
    var date = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    var timeFormat = 'h:mm tt';
    var hours = addHours ? ' ' + timeFormat : '';
    return Date.parse(date).toString('dd/MM/yyyy' + hours);
}
```

the object `event` is provided by [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) when an event is clicked. Each event is composed by a `start` and an `end` date. I checked also both dates with `isValid` method provided by `momentjs`, and both are valid.

I also have the variable `timeFormat` which specify the time format, and `hours` specify if add also the hours to the final date.

Comment: `Date.parse(date)` returns a Number

Comment: why are you formatting the state into a string, then parsing that string back into a date, then formatting that date back into a string?

Comment: the first line`event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');` extract the date from the `event.start` object and parse it into a specific format. I get the `timestamp` of `date`, the problem is that I have some problem on `.toString` method.

Comment: I agree with Amy, I can't understand the idea behind your code. Since `event.start` is a moment object, you can use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to display its value in your preferred format (e.g. `event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY')` or `event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a')`) or use [`toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) _to get a copy of the native Date object that Moment.js wraps_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Date.parse(date)
```

Returns a timestamp, a number. Calling toString() method on number by defaults make it a string, but with argument it can convert that number to different base e.g hexadecimals.

You might want to look into moment.js library you have to do those formatting operations.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a date format to the .toString() method.

This works only for Number.prototype.toString to specify the radix (integer between 2 and 36 specifying the base to use for representing numeric values):

Answer (score 0):

## Offtopic but related

Some minutes ago the author of this question asked about not existing method parseExact for the Date object. I typed answer, but the question was deleted. I think anyway it can help to @sfarzoso so I am answering there.

---

Method `parseExact` is not a native method in JavaScript. It is appended to the prototype of the Data object by library Datejs

You can find it there

> [Date.js parseExact() not parsing 4 digit years when passed in as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567476/date-js-parseexact-not-parsing-4-digit-years-when-passed-in-as-an-array)

and there

> [Date.js parseExact with french culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632928/date-js-parseexact-with-french-culture)

And the library is there

> https://github.com/datejs/Datejs

And docs of parse exact you can find on the end of file

> https://github.com/datejs/Datejs/blob/master/src/parser.js